# How to optimize SELECT statement with multiple sub-queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a query that I'm trying to optimize but haven't had much success. There are two tables, one with the main data and one with timestamps of when specific events occurred. The tables are relational using a common key of adID. I am trying to perform a query that pulls in all of the timestamps and other data from the main table. I have it working but I am trying to optimize so it runs faster.

```
SELECT a.ID,a.repID,a.artistID,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 c.timestamp
    FROM Tracking AS c
    WHERE statusID = 4
    AND c.ID = a.ID
    ORDER BY c.timestamp ASC

) 
AS created,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 d.timestamp
    FROM Tracking AS d
    WHERE statusID = 5
    AND d.ID = a.ID
    ORDER BY d.timestamp ASC
)
AS claimed,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 p.timestamp
    FROM Tracking AS p
    WHERE statusID = 6
    AND p.ID = a.ID
    ORDER BY p.timestamp ASC
)
AS proof,
(
    SELECT TOP 1 v.timestamp
    FROM Tracking AS v
    WHERE statusID = 8
    AND v.ID = a.ID
    ORDER BY v.timestamp ASC
)
AS approved,
(
    SELECT count(ID)
    FROM Tracking AS t
    WHERE statusID = 6
    AND t.ID = a.ID
)
AS proofcount
FROM Advertising AS a
WHERE a.statusID = 8
```

Any help on this is appreciated. I'm not too familiar with SQL Server so I am not too well versed in optimizing queries such as these.

Comment: How many rows does the query return? What indexes do you have on `Tracking`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
SELECT a.ID,
  a.repID,
  a.artistID,
  min(case when t.statusID = 4 then t.timestamp end) created,
  min(case when t.statusID = 5 then t.timestamp end) claimed,
  min(case when t.statusID = 6 then t.timestamp end) proof,
  min(case when t.statusID = 8 then t.timestamp end) approved,
  count(case when t.statusID = 6 then id end) proofcount
FROM Advertising AS a
LEFT JOIN Tracking t
  on a.id = t.id
WHERE a.statusID = 8
GROUP BY a.ID, a.repID, a.artistID;
```

Comment: @jgraening You are welcome, I am happy to help. This is basically a `PIVOT`, you could also implement that function to perform this task as well.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following query gets to what you want:

```
select id, repid, artistid,
       max(case when statusId = 4 and seqnum = 1 then timestamp end),
       max(case when statusId = 5 and seqnum = 1 then timestamp end),
       max(case when statusId = 6 and seqnum = 1 then timestamp end),
       max(case when statusId = 8 and seqnum = 1 then timestamp end),
       sum(case when statusId = 6 then 1 else 0 end)
from (select a.ID, a.repID, a.artistID, t.statusId, t.timestamp
             row_number() over (partition by a.id, t.statusId order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from advertising a left outer join
           tracking t
           on a.id = t.id
    ) t
where seqnum = 1
group by id, repid, artistid
```

It joins the tables together and identifies the earliest record using `row_number()`.  It then selects only these records and groups by the other fields.

Your query also filters only those records that have `statusid = 8`.  I'm not sure if this is intentional.  If so, then you want this `having` clause at the end of the query:

```
having sum(case when statusId = 8 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```